# post request body is null in retrofit kotlin but the response code is okay(200) plus data is stored in that post request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

**This is API endpoint where i am sending a json object through post request **

```
package com.example.samplegayar
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import org.json.JSONObject
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*

interface ApiEndpoints {
     @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
     @POST("/api/user-profile/")
     fun getProfileInfo(@Body jsonObject: JsonObject): Call<ProfileInfo>
}
```

My activity file goes here

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_)
    val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ApiEndpoints::class.java)
    val payerReg = JsonObject()
    payerReg.addProperty("user_email", "test@gmail.com")
    payerReg.addProperty("streamer_email", "test2@gmail.com")

    val call = request.getProfileInfo(payerReg)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ProfileInfo>{

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProfileInfo>, response: Response<ProfileInfo>) {
            Log.d("response",response.body().toString())
            Log.d("response",response.code().toString())
            Log.d("response",response.raw().toString())

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("response","you got success mate")
                Log.d("response", response.body().toString())
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProfileInfo>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ProfileActivity, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             Log.d("failure","you are a loser mate")
        }
    })
}
```

here is my retrofit service code

```
package com.example.samplegayar

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object ServiceBuilder {
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://dev.gayar.net/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check if the key "user_email" is valid or not? Your API is returning invalid key "user_email"

Comment: sorry my bad i edited that part still facing same problem